# TurtleSim Display Linux on Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, ros

Currently following this tutorial [enter link description here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingNodes)

I have Ubuntu installed on my windows machine, using the Ubuntu terminal. When I run the following command

```
rosrun turtlesim turtlesim_node
```

I get this error in the terminal
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzSdz.png)

I have install Xming as found in some other places, and this is running in the background, but still the error persists. Anyone run into this?

I am using ROS melodic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use x410 for the GUI of WSL [Website Link](https://token2shell.com/x410/)

I have tried to use Ubuntu 18.04 WSL and ROS Melodic with Turtlebot and Rviz GUI running well.

[image: Turtlebot]

[image: Rviz]

Comment: yes, but you can give an explanation, not only show that you did it?

Comment: The X410 website has explained the installation and the usage of X410 as an X Display server clearly. You just have to install ROS and X410 then run everything normally